# traceId and spanId is not printing in the logs for Spring boot 3.2.x distributed tracing

Tags: java, spring-boot, open-telemetry, micrometer, distributed-tracing

I have implemented distributed tracing in my spring cloud microservices using micrometer and opentelemetry

```
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel'
    implementation 'io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin'
```

everything is working fine logs are exporting to zipkin server and I can see the traceid and spanid in zipkin ui, but in logs traceid and spanid are not printing
I have tried below solutions

added logging pattern level
`logging.pattern.level: "%5p [${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}]"`

I'm using both web and webflux so for webflux projects I have added
`Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation();`

still in logs it's not printing `INFO [gateway,,] 8 --- [gateway] [           main]`, can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: That's not a lot of information (e.g.: which versions you use?). I would recommend creating a demo app using start.spring.io with the latest dependencies just to see it working then you can bring your app and the demo together to see where they brake. Also, if you are using Boot 3.1 or newer, that property is not needed anymore.